# how to remove include module error in angular ?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I make a simple demo in my Pc which is working fine .But when I make fiddle to ask Question say
**Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myapp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.**

can you please tell why it is occur ? I am getting data n my pc.Actually my real Question how to refresh or call same webservice after some tome mean after 1 minutes.As in jquery we have setinterval function .how I will achieve in this angular ?

here is fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/acboLcv2/1/

```
var app=angular.module("myapp");

app.factory('test', function($http) {

    //This whole object is returned when the Service runs. It is a singleton
    //and its properties can be accessed from any controller

    return {


        stationDashBoard: function(callback,error) {
            $http.get('http://184.106.159.143:8180/FGRailApps/jservices/rest/a/departure?crsCode=VIC').success(callback).error(error);
        }
    }
});
function departureContrl($scope,test){
    $scope.loading=true;
    test.stationDashBoard(function(data){
        console.log(data);
        $scope.data=data.data;
        $scope.loading=false;
        //alert(data);
    },function(error){
        alert('error')
    }) ;

}
```

Thanks

Comment: First of all. To create new module in Angular you should pass 2 parametres `angular.module('moduleName', [])`.. moduleName and dependencies array

Comment: @max still same error

Comment: Change your scope load option to wrap in head or body and as @Max said use the setter syntax for the module declaration. http://jsfiddle.net/r4bs1hrc/

Comment: @PSL I got it I also make in plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/CwtfuDQm2xaBBnWkr5Rb?p=preview

Comment: @user944513 yeah plunker is better than fiddle :)

Comment: Please disable security of browser than you see the  data also .But how I will refresh screen after 2or 1 min.Mean I need to update my list after 1 min to again hit the server and get data from server and display the updated one.As in jquery I have setInterval what we have in

Comment: @user944513 You mean you want to refresh the data by making `stationDashBoard` call every 1-2 min? Try this way http://plnkr.co/edit/ly43m5?p=info

Comment: @user944513 Use services $timeout or $interval. It's usual setTimeout and setInterval, but they call $scope.$apply in the end

Comment: how can you please give some change in my plunker ?

Comment: @user944513 check the plunker in my prev comment. I cannot save in your plunker.. :)

Comment: @user944513 to calculate proper time use this formula: 1000 * 60 * <minutes>

Comment: Thanks all ..I got it ..last take a example If I have 100 item in list when I hit service.I scroll my list upto 51 item .Now I see list after after 51 .Now refresh function call and it update the list focus come to top of row how we manage the focus remain on 51 element.In other word can we get the scoll position before refresh and scoll the list upto that position

Answer (score 0):

So there's a few things with your site you need to focus on:

#### Getting rid of the module error:

I think it's fixed, but heuristically I suggest:

1. Ensure that the declaration of an angular module includes the empty array as as already been mentioned. This *is* necessary, thusly:

   angular.module("test", []);
2. Ensure you reference the angular app in the html. I suggest body for most applications:

#### CORS error

You're trying to load data from a different domain with $http.get(...). This [won't work](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) unless you do some kind of CORS hackery or you get the data from the same domain. Ie, you'd have to host this code on `http://184.106.159.143:8180` (in this example).

#### Polling request

You're asking about fetching data from a server every n seconds. This is quite easy and the method you suggest with setTimeout() would work but would need to be integrated into the angular Digest Loop:

I suggest using [$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) because it will work with angular's rendering something like this (this is pseudocode, not tested):

```
var fetchFromServer(cb){

    $timeout(function(){

       $http.get(...).then(function(data){
        //Do something with the retrieved data
        cb(fetchFromServer); //Recurse
       });

    }, 15000);
};

fetchFromServer(fetchFromServer);
```

Otherwise you can use setTimeout as you normally would in javascript, but don't forget to call the $scope.$apply() method to render things in angular if you do it outside the digest loop or else it will appear as if there has been no effect.